# Extending tp-link configuraton

Tags: raspberry-pi, powerline-networking

I've 3 TP-LINK TL-PA411 AV500. 1 tp-link is connected to router and power socket while other two are connected to other rooms around house.

I planned to purchase more tp-link adapters and also connect these to existing configuration but was informed by local electrical store that my existing tp-link infrastructure cannot be extended in this way. In short when each tp-link box-set is just configured to work with adapters for just that set so cannot daisy-chain multiple sets together.

Is this true ? If I purchased additional TP-LINK TL-PA411 AV500 will these work in same way as existing adapters ? If not how can I extend this configuration ?

The reason I use power line adapters is the wi-fi signal is weak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's true that some adapters come pre-paired, it is always possible to change the network key whenever necessary using HomePlug AV management software.

- TP-Link provides *tpPLC*, other vendors have their own (in practice they're all compatible).
- Some models (e.g. the TL-WPA* series) have this function as part of their own web configuration.
- On Linux, you can use the `openplc` tools.

Finally, all adapters have a "Pair" button – press it first on one of the existing member adapters, then on the new adapter, and it'll pick up the network key. See the [user guide](http://www.tplink.com/resources/document/TL-PA411(AU_V2_UG_1910011029.pdf) for more details.

Comment: so I can purchase additional ' TP-LINK TL-PA411 AV500 ' adapters and pair with my existing configuration , my initial assertion is correct ?